# Calculating resolution rate per sub category in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame like below. I have made the data frame shorter to put the idea across easily

| `Category | Issue | WK 1 | WK 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pending B | C | 1 | 2 |
| Pending B | E | 3 | 4 |
| Pending B | R | 4 | 5 |
| Pending C | C | 1 | 2 |
| Pending C | E | 3 | 4 |
| Pending C | R | 4 | 5 |
| Resolved | C | 1 | 2 |
| Resolved | E | 3 | 4 |
| Resolved | R | 4 | 5 |
| ----------: | --------------: | ----: | :---: |
| Total |  | 24 | 33 |

`    Using the formulars below:

```
formular for WK 1 column

C-WK 1/(Total WK 1 - (sum of pending C WK 1))
E-WK 1/(Total WK 1 - (sum of pending C WK 1))
R-WK 1/(Total WK 1 - (sum of pending C WK 1))


formular for WK 2 column

C-WK 2/(Total WK 2 - (sum of pending C WK 2))
E-WK 2/(Total WK 2 - (sum of pending C WK 2))
R-WK 2/(Total WK 2 - (sum of pending C WK 2))`
```

at the end i want to have a data frame like below.

| Category | Issue | WK 1 | WK 2 | WK 1(R) | WK 2(R) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resolved | C | 1 | 2 | 0.0625 | 0.090909 |
| Resolved | E | 3 | 4 | 0.1875 | 0.181818 |
| Resolved | R | 4 | 5 | 0.25 | 0.227273 |
| ----------: | --------------: | ----: | :---: | -------: | :------: |

Comment: @mozway, can you kindly assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a function to calculate the columns of `WK 1(R)` and `WK 2(R)` and after that, use `.loc` to select the rows where `"Category"` is `"Resolved"`.

```py
def calculate_wk_resolution(df):
    # Calculate WK 1(R) and WK 2(R)
    df["WK 1(R)"] = df["WK 1"] / (df["WK 1"].sum() - df[df["Category"] == "Pending C"]["WK 1"].sum())
    df["WK 2(R)"] = df["WK 2"] / (df["WK 2"].sum() - df[df["Category"] == "Pending C"]["WK 2"].sum())
    
calculate_wk_resolution(df)

out = df.loc[df["Category"] == "Resolved", ["Category", "Issue", "WK 1", "WK 2", "WK 1(R)", "WK 2(R)"]]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Category  Issue  WK 1  WK 2  WK 1(R)  WK 2(R)
6  Resolved     C     1     2   0.0625  0.090909
7  Resolved     E     3     4   0.1875  0.181818
8  Resolved     R     4     5   0.2500  0.227273
```